# Making a IoT Motion Sensor w/ Security Camera

Tags: camera, home-automation, motion, picamera

I'm trying to find the easiest and most efficient way to create one. I have the below already, is there anything else that I would need? Where can I find some code for me to copy. I don't necessarily want to learn code at this moment in time so I prefer an already completed project code.

- Raspberry Pi 3 B+
- Jumper Cables
- Motion Sensor
- Pi Camera 1080p (In the process of purchasing it)

The project would need to send an automated email if motion is triggered and also attach a photo of the intruder.

**EDIT: Is this automated email compatible with all providers?**

Comment: https://www.electromaker.io/project/view/pir-sensor-camera-room-security-email-alerts maybe? Searching the web for 'raspberry pi pir camera email' should give more results

Comment: In different style you  have said - "Google it" It is not against the "be nice " rules?

Comment: @JanHus - the OP has been a member for 5 months (not new) and has asked 3 other questions ...  he's has asked this type of question once before (basically a request to do all the research for him) and his other two questions showed an equal level of research (i.e. none) - so I don't think "here's what to search for" is at all "not nice"

Comment: @JanHus I actually give a 'fully qualified` solution *plus* a way to find more. Other option would have been downvoting and / or flagging. Would that have been nicer?

Comment: @JaromandaX I just prefer others to explain ideas and opinions and try and build my knowledge from that and if there are any problems and workarounds for their projects if they've done something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully made a fully funcional security camera using this link below. It includes customisable automated emails:

[PiCamera Motion Detection](https://www.bouvet.no/bouvet-deler/utbrudd/building-a-motion-activated-security-camera-with-the-raspberry-pi-zero)

Answer (score 1):

The [motion application](https://motion-project.github.io/index.html), available in the Raspbian repos (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install motion`) can do what you're asking without the need for jumper cables or motion detector, though maybe you want the motion detector.

The `motion` application can be configured to watch for motion using the camera, and when motion is detected, it can automatically snap a photo, series of photos, or take a video. Using the `on_motion_detected` option, it can then run a script that, for example, would send you an email with the photo(s) or footage attached.

Furthermore, motion can be configured such that only certain regions within the camera's field of vision are watched for motion. In other words, if you have the camera pointed at your front lawn, and the street happens to be in the camera's field of vision, the portion of the image wherein the street lies can be ignored by the motion detection feature.

As an added benefit, `motion` exposes a web interface that allows for live viewing of the camera feed.

Comment: Thankyou! Now I don't need any extra wires! One question though, can this work with automated emails if motion is triggered?

Comment: If you have a way to send emails from the command line, yes it will with the `on_motion_detected` option. As an alternative to email, it should work with something like pushbullet too. Though services like pushbullet often only allow you to send a limited number of messages/month for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Motion Detection camera "***solution in a box***", try ***open-ipcamera***.

**Features**

- **Motion Detection:** Software-based, using the ***Motion*** package.
- **Cloud Storage:**  images are written to a a local USB Flash disk, punted up to Dropbox, then the local copies deleted.  This ensures storage never fills to 100%.  It also ensures if the camera is stolen the images survive and the bad guys can't see what picutres were captured ;-)
- **Alerting:** there are several: a) on motion detection events b) Heat- set **WARN** & **SHUTDOWN** thresholds c) IPaddress:  When camera starts it will email it's address so you can find a headless pi on a network- ie: when tethering it to a phone's Internet connection.
- **In-Place Upgrades:** ***open-ipcamera*** ships with an upgrade facility so you can easily security patch and upgrade your production camera.
- **Dual IPv4/IPv6 stack:** Support for IPv6 even allows for direct access to the camera without requiring a DNAT to be configured.
- **Easy Configuration:**. Just clone the repo into Pi user's home, plug-in your local details into two config files `variables-secure.sh` and `variables.sh` then execute the install script `./open-ipcamera-config.sh`.

Has lots of other features which are detailed in both the ***open-ipcamera*** wiki and the repo's `README.md` file

More detailed instructions with everything you need to know about ***open-ipcamera***:

[open-ipcamera Wiki](https://github.com/open-ipcamera/open-ipcamera/wiki)

[open-ipcamera YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDCqFD71kgL347W6a9RwtmQ/videos)

HTH